# How to inject multiple named dependencies using InversifyJS?

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

Let's imagine the following class hierarchy:

```
interface Weapon {
}

interface BladedWeapon extends Weapon {
}

class Katana implements BladedWeapon {
}

class Stick implements Weapon {
}
```

Current bindings are following:

```
container.bind<Weapon>('Weapon').to(Stick).whenTargetNamed('stick');
container.bind<Weapon>('Weapon').to(Katana).whenTargetNamed('katana');
```

In one part of my code I would like to get all instaces of `Weapon` interface:

```
@multiInject('Weapon') weapons: Weapon[];
```

In the other part I would like to get katana:

```
@inject('Weapon') @named('katana') katana: Katana;
```

The problem is InversifyJS cannot perform multi-injection due to named bindings:

```
 Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: 'Weapon'
```

How to solve this issue?

P.S. I use InversifyJS 6.0.1

Comment: I had the same issue so I created an issue (and use your example). You can follow it here: https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I found not clean, but working way to solve the issue:

```
container.bind<Weapon>('Weapon').to(Stick);
container.bind<Weapon>('Weapon').to(Katana);

container.bind<Katana>('Katana').toDynamicValue(context => {
    const weapons = context.container.getAll<Weapon>('Weapon');
    for (const weapon of weapons) {
        if (isKatana(weapon)) {
            return weapon;
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Katana is not found in DI container');
}).whenTargetNamed('katana');
```

In the code above I don't use names while defining bindings that could be injected using multi-injection. For specific weapon I create dynamic named binding and just search required dependency among registered.